# Mocking Cypress timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, cypress

I'm writing a Cypress test for showing a timestamp upon a div hover.

The tooltip content is built from a date string, something like `content = format(new Date("2023-01-01T12:00:00Z"), 'dd MMM yyy HH:mm')`.

Using `date-fns` as a date formatting library.

Problem is, browser is converting the Date string to my local browser's timestamp, and I'd like to get rid of this behaviour so that CI doesn't randomly fail because of timezone differences.

I already fixed this problem in a Jest test, by making use of the [timezone-mock](https://github.com/Jimbly/timezone-mock) library.

Inside a Jest test:

```
  beforeAll(() => {
    timezoneMock.register('UTC')
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    timezoneMock.unregister()
  })
```

date strings are no longer converted based on timezone, they stay in UTC.

Tried something similar in Cypress, but it doesn't work

```
describe('Tooltip', () => {
  before(() => {
    timezoneMock.register('UTC')

    // Prints date converted to local timezone
    console.log('mock', new timezoneMock._Date)

    cy.visit('/link')
  })

  after(() => {
    timezoneMock.unregister()
  })
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be better to set a specific date to test instead of relying on the local date wherever you're running it https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock#Specify-a-now-timestamp

You're testing the formatting of the date I assume, not if new Date() is working.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think you're right.

My biggest mental block was how to get from a specific mocked Date to an ISO string that my function knew how to format, and just discovered `.toISOString()` after I read your comment.

Thanks a lot!